# Получение данных с класса в фрагмент

Tags: android

Есть: 1) Активити, 2) Класс, 3) Фрагмент.
В активити есть обьект класса - user. Мне надо его получить во фрагменте.
Есть решение:

1) Создаю новый класс.

```
public class CurrentUser {
    public static User CurrentUser;
}
```

2) В активити делаю:

```
CurrentUser.CurrentUser = user;
```

3) В Фрагменте получаю данные:

```
CurrentUser.CurrentUser.getName()
```

Вопрос. Почему нельзя сделать конструктор в классе, передать в него данные с активити. А с помощью метода get получить эти данные во фрагменте?

Comment: Имена переменных в Java пишутся с маленькой буквы, чтобы отличать их от имен классов

Answer (score 3):

Потому что у вас данные хранятся в статической переменной. Для того чтобы передать данные из активити во фрагмент можно сделать так:

Создают интерфейс:

```
public interface onSomeListener {
    public String someEvent();
}
```

Ваше активити наследует этот интерфейс, и в метод `someEvent()` возвращает ваш объект(вместо `String` нужно указать ваш класс)

В методе onAttach фрагмента, вы получаете `context`, который кастуете к `onSomeListener`. И во фрагменте дергаете у этого объекта метод `someEvent()`, для получения вашего объекта. Так можно сделать работу не только из активити во фрагмент, но и наоборот. Пример [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html).

Второй вариант, это сделать у фрагмента сеттер, найти его через `FragmentManager` и передать через сеттер ваш объект.

Третий вариант это если ваш объект `Serializable`, то передавать его в аргумент фрагмента.

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putExtra("key", yourObject);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```